# Is there a default method in java interfaces equivalent in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In java, we can write default methods in interfaces with implementations. And further use this in classes where this interface has been implemented. Also, it is not compulsory to implement this default method.

I was trying to find something similar in Flutter. In flutter, it asks me to implement all methods. Else I get an error 'Missing concrete implementations of '.

*So, is there something I can do to get the same overall output?*

Apologies if I sound vague here. Do let me know in the comments if more information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are searching for abstract classes , not interface.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are searching for abstract class. Its the same concept in dart as well.

```
abstract class Animal{
  void breathe(){
    print("Breathing");
  }  
  void move();
}

class FlyingAnimal extends Animal{
  @override
  void move() {
    print("fly");
  }
}


class WalkingAnimal extends Animal{
  @override
  void move() {
    print("walk");
  }
}
```

```
void main(){
  FlyingAnimal flyingAnimal=FlyingAnimal();
  flyingAnimal.move();
  flyingAnimal.breathe();
}
```

Flyinganimal can breathe and move, where breath is inherited from parent class Animal.
I hope this makes sense to you and helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the equivalent in Dart is use both `mixin` and `interface`.

In my opinion, in dart `interface` is just contract with no implementation and `mixin` is for code block reuse.

Java `interface` default method, is a contract with method that can be reuse.

So in dart, I prefer to write like this.

interface:

```dart
abstract interface class Chunk {
  Uint8List get data;

  Uint8List get hash;

  String get hexHash;

  int get length;

  int get offset;

  ChunkMetadata toChunkMetadata();
}
```

mixin:

```dart
mixin ChunkToChunkMetadataMixin implements Chunk {
  @override
  ChunkMetadata toChunkMetadata() {
    return SimpleChunkMetadata(
        offset: offset, length: length, hash: hash, hexHash: hexHash);
  }
}
```

implement class:

```dart
final class SimpleChunk with ChunkToChunkMetadataMixin implements Chunk {
  @override
  final Uint8List data;
  @override
  final Uint8List hash;
  @override
  final String hexHash;
  @override
  final int offset;

  @override
  int get length => data.length;

  SimpleChunk({
    required this.data,
    required this.offset,
    required this.hash,
  })  : assert(data.isNotEmpty, "Data must not be empty"),
        assert(hash.isNotEmpty, "Hash must not be empty"),
        assert(offset >= 0, "Offset must be positive"),
        hexHash = hex.encoder.convert(hash);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to provide implementation fir already implemented methods (it'd have no sense), but you must implement all **abstract** methods.